# Getting unauthorized with Devise & Rails Admin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, rails-admin

I'm trying to setup **Rails_admin** with devise in order to force authentication to go into the admin panel but I'm getting  **unauthorized** messages and being redirected to the login page.

I've done this kind of integration between Devise and Rails_Admin before and didn't have any problem but this time I'm getting a lot of troubles with it. Any idea of what might be happening?

Thanks in advance

```
  config.authenticate_with do
    warden.authenticate! scope: :user
  end
  config.current_user_method(&:current_user)
```

Comment: Did you add the routes for the scope you are working with?

Comment: Yes I added them @user944938
devise_for :users
mount RailsAdmin::Engine => '/admin', as: 'rails_admin'

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. Changing the session_store key fixed the problem for me.

```
# config/initializers/session_store.rb
# Be sure to restart your server when you modify this file.

Rails.application.config.session_store :cookie_store, key: '_changed_key_session'
```

This comment helped me to find this solution : https://github.com/activeadmin/activeadmin/issues/2957#issuecomment-49748165.